# Powerline fonts not working on Airline

Tags: plugin-airline, plugin-powerline

So, I installed the Airline plugin which is working quite nicely. But, I'd like it a bit sweeter. So I went to Powerline.

I installed patched fonts from https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Hack and modified my `.vimrc` like so

[image]
But, as you can see, it doesn't seem to work correctly...

Is it a font issue or is it something else?

Comment: I would vote on font/font size issue. From what I see in the README on font homepage, Powerline glyphs are in Regular part of font, but there might be a problem when there are also Bold parts of text (like `NORMAL`). I would suggest trying some other Powerline fonts, preferably from the official Powerline Github repo.

Comment: I can only see one font un the official repo https://github.com/powerline/powerline/tree/develop/font which doesn't change anything once installed

Comment: I see a lot more :P https://github.com/powerline/fonts

Comment: Indeed, but, that's from where I got the font (Hack) which is not currently working :)

Comment: Ah, didn't noticed that, but I used Source Code Pro, Liberation and few other from there and they worked, but didn't noticed that Hack font back then, so still I recommend trying other fonts. I had similar issue at some point - but I struggle to recall what fixed that exactly.

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue, but on urxvt terminal. There, the font width gets calculated rather than trusting the font (because, apparently, some fonts aren't accurate about sizing). When anti-aliasing is enabled, it makes some of those characters appear an extra pixel wide, which then breaks the block-art symbols like you see. Fixes for urxvt include turning off antialiasing or using the `-letsp` option to adjust the calculated width. How to fix your situation will depend on the terminal you use.

Answer (score 6):

See [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/how-to-fix-status-bar-symbols-in-airline-plugin). Specifically, paste this into your .vimrc.

```
" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''

Comment: This didn't solve my problem.