# Why some information can't been shown at status bar with iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, unicode, macos, iterm2, spacevim

Installed vim with [SpaceVim](http://spacevim.org) on macOS.

When ran `vim` in the `iTerm2` terminal, the information can't been shown rightly at status bar. Much of them been shown as `?`. Why?

[image]

Comment: Possibly [a duplicate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3359/1841)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpaceVim uses a built-in modular status line, which depends on a power line patched font. These fonts include extra symbols that render as arrows in the terminal.

You can find pre-patched fonts here: https://github.com/powerline/fonts.
I’m pretty sure that repository also has instructions for patching an arbitrary font if none of the fonts it provides are to your liking.

After installing one you’ll need to switch to using that font in iTerm2.